# I can't start my django project after some code updates. I was revert everything back, but it still not working

Tags: python-3.x, django

I don't think that error in code. I did `git reset --hard <commit>` to last work version, and it was still broken

The error when i'm use runserver command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crm/crm/settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/club2/crm/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/club2/crm/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute  
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crm/crm/settings'
```

Also I think this part can be useful
I hide some information because Stackoverflow can't post my question

crm/settings:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'the_key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*',
    '109.68.213.180'
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'accounts',
    'work'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crm.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    # DB
    },
    'OPTIONS': {
        # option
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
    #  validators
]

# custom user model and auth system
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'accounts.auth_user.UserAuth',
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# the date and some url here

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6gVm.png)

Manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'crm.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I didn't found any info about my situation

Comment: you should run with `--settings='crm.crm.settings', not `--settings=crm/crm/settings` or anything similar.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem where i should run it?
or with ```python3 crm/manage.py runserver ip:port --settings='crm.crm.settings'```

Comment: I can't found this (crm/settings) in my project

Comment: Looks like the problem is in `manage.py` can you share the code for this file

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PEYwH1LX1Rfm1HNqS9em_VbF5YdSCRIg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChesterZed don't share code in google or don't post code as images. ALWAYS paste code directly into question. With what command do you `runserver`?

Comment: Yes I do with command ```python3 manage.py runserver ip:port```
(It's worked yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

You have `'crm/crm/settings'` in your manage.py. It should be with dots (`.`) not with backslashes (`/`) and `crm` should be written only once.

manage.py:

```
# BAD
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "crm/crm/settings")

# GOOD
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "crm.settings")
```

Comment: I pin screenshot with manage.py

Comment: Don't pin screenshots of code. What command do you use to runserver?

Comment: ```python3 manage.py runserver ip:port```
(It's worked yesterday)